# DirectX: empty sample compile error

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

Greetings I am trying to build an empty project of Direct3D 9 with Visual Studio 2017 which can be found in Sample browser.

I downloaded whole project files and compiled the project usin VS2017 but I got one error in this line

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2668   'abs': ambiguous call to overloaded function    EmptyProject    c:\users\myid\desktop\direct3d_source\emptyproject\dxut\core\dxutenum.cpp   3975

and the code is below

```
 float fCurRanking = abs( float( displayMode.RefreshRate.Numerator ) / fDenom1  -
                                         float( refreshRateMatch.Numerator ) / fDenom2 );
```

To remove ambiguous function call, I used cast operator such as (int) or (long).

(want to use float or double cast function but that brings syntax error)

but I just got these errors

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  EmptyProject    C:\Users\myid\Desktop\EmptyProject\Debug\EmptyProject.exe   1

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __vsnwprintf referenced in function "long __stdcall StringVPrintfWorkerW(unsigned short *,unsigned int,unsigned int *,unsigned short const *,char *)" (?StringVPrintfWorkerW@@YGJPAGIPAIPBGPAD@Z)    EmptyProject    C:\Users\myid\Desktop\EmptyProject\dxerr.lib(dxerrw.obj)    1

How to deal with this? I readed the LNK1120, LNK2019 pages but don`t know where is the exact error is

Comment: Errors fairly often depend on context, so providing just a single line of code is not always enough. In this case, I would recommend including at least the declarations of `fDenom1` and `fDenom2`, possibly the entire function in which this line occurs (you can use a comment to point out which line is identified by the error message).